# Magento Theme Hierarchy

Tags: magento, themes

Currently I am moving the theme file from `Default/XXX to XXX/default` . From

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

I found out that Magento searches the file in following sequence:

`Package/theme->Package/default->Base->default`.

Is it possible to make it search the theme like this: `Package/theme1->Package/theme2->Package/default->Base->default?`

Besides that, will the magento still be loading the `default/default` theme?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento system will fall back the files using below order.

Using DEFAULT package with DEFAULT theme

> 1) app/design/frontend/{DEFAULT}/{DEFAULT}
>
> 2) app/design/frontend/base/{DEFAULT}

Using DEFAULT package with Custom theme

> 1) app/design/frontend/{DEFAULT}/{MY-THEME}
>
> 2) app/design/frontend/{DEFAULT}/{DEFAULT}
>
> 3) app/design/frontend/base/{DEFAULT}

If you are using the Custom Package with Custom theme.

> 1) app/design/frontend/{CUSTOM-PACKAGE}/{MY-THEME}
>
> 2) app/design/frontend/{CUSTOM-PACKAGE}/{DEFAULT}
>
> 3) app/design/frontend/base/{DEFAULT}

These above order only magento files are fallback.

Comment: Is my answer useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but as I stumbled across this I would like to add the newest fallback hierarchy.

Since 1.9 you can define the fallbacks in a theme.xml in your theme folder. See http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes for further information.